# Android >= 30: Inflated view wont show

Tags: android, view, android-inflate

I upgraded my SDK from 23 to 30 and it seems that now some things work differently.
In a fragment, I want to inflate another View, though it wont be shown.
I can confirm that the hiding of the former View succeeds.

What I exactely changed was the last parameter of .inflate( as true value caused the app to crash.

```
    private void newMemo() {
    if (newMemoRoot == null) {
        newMemoRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_newmemo, container, false);
        newMemoConstraintLayout = newMemoRoot.findViewById(R.id.newMemoConstraintLayout);
        newMemoEditText = newMemoRoot.findViewById(R.id.newMemoEditText);
        forMeRadioButton = newMemoRoot.findViewById(R.id.newMemo_forMeRadioButton);
        forAllRadioButton = newMemoRoot.findViewById(R.id.newMemo_forAllRadioButton);
        forMeRadioButton.setChecked(true);

        sendNewButton = newMemoRoot.findViewById(R.id.newMemo_sendButton);
        sendNewButton.setOnClickListener((View) -> sendNew());

        cancelNewMemoButton = newMemoRoot.findViewById(R.id.newMemo_cancelButton);
        cancelNewMemoButton.setOnClickListener((View) -> disableNewMemoView());
    }
    memoConstraintLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    newMemoConstraintLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

[image]

The views XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/newMemoConstraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:backgroundTint="#858585">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/newMemo_cancelButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:text="Abbrechen"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/newMemo_sendButton" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/newMemo_sendButton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/newMemo_forMeRadioButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Für mich" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/newMemo_forAllRadioButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Für Alle" />
</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/newMemo_sendButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:text="Senden"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/newMemo_cancelButton"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/newMemoEditText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:background="#E8E6E6"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/radioGroup"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The Gradle setup:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion '32.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 30
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 2

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0'
    def work_version = "2.3.0"
    // (Java only)
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:$work_version"
    // optional - RxJava2 support
    implementation "androidx.work:work-rxjava2:$work_version"
    // optional - GCMNetworkManager support
    implementation "androidx.work:work-gcm:$work_version"
    // optional - Test helpers
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.work:work-testing:$work_version"
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-tls:4.10.0-RC1"
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.1'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.1'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.11.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.3.0'
    implementation 'org.conscrypt:conscrypt-android:2.5.1'
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha25"
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.0.0-alpha25'
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.0.0-alpha25"
    // If you want to additionally use the CameraX View class
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha25"
    // If you want to additionally use the CameraX Extensions library
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.0.0-alpha24"


    def room_version = "2.2.6"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

}
```

Comment: "What I exactely changed was the last parameter of .inflate( as true value caused the app to crash." – That parameter indicates whether the inflated `View` should be automatically added to the parent, which would explain why you don't see it when you set it to `false`. The stack trace from the crash is what you should be looking at.

Comment: Ye thought so too, unfortunately there is no stacktrace to see in logcat. When debugging there is just one line. Though debugging the sdk is what Im at atm.

Comment: "Ye thought so too, unfortunately there is no stacktrace to see in logcat." – They can be easy to miss. Make sure you don't any filters on, or have the wrong process selected, etc. "When debugging there is just one line." – What's that, exactly? "Though debugging the sdk is what Im at atm." – That sounds like the long way 'round. If this were me, I'd start by figuring out exactly what is causing the issue. Are you sure `container` is not null there? Is it the particular layout used there? Or does inflating and adding anything cause the crash? Is it maybe one particular tag in the layout? Etc.

Comment: Hi Mike, I am gratefull for your comment full of experience! And from mine, I totally agree with what you say. For the moment, as its just a private app and Ive just gotten into 31, I created a second Layout in the same Fragment which I set GONE/VISIBLE instead of inflating a new xml. Though Im curious too how this thing actually works and I will pick that up in the future.
Kind regards and thank you again!